# confused with imaginary to rectangular in quotient and product form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

a) The equation of the line through $2 + 3i$ and $0$ can be written as
$$az + b \overline{z} = 0$$
for some complex numbers $a$ and $b$. What is the quotient $b/a$ in rectangular form. Should I graph it out?

b) The equation of the line through $2+3i$ which is perpendicular to the line through $0$ and $2+3i$ has equation
$$az + b\overline{z} = 26,$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constant complex numbers. Find the product $ab$ in rectangular form.  Same concept... I am confused on how to approach.

Answer (score 1):

(a) since line pass through affix 0  and affix $z_{1}=2+3i$ 
so, it's equation will be

$z\ \overline {z_{1}}-\overline {z_{}} \ z_{1}=0\implies a=\overline {z_{1}}=2-3i=\sqrt{13}\ e^{-i{{\theta_{1}}}}\ \ $ and   $\\b=z_{1}=2+3i=\sqrt{13}\ e^{i\theta_{1}}\implies\dfrac{b}{a}=e^{2i\theta_{1}}$ where $\theta _{1}=tan ^{-1}\frac{3}{2}$

(b) equation of line $\perp$ to line (a) and which also passes through $2+3i$ (and of course through any point $z$ ) will be

$[0-(2+3i)](2-3i-\overline z)+ [(0-(2-3i))](2+3i-z)=0\implies(2+3i)\overline z +(2-3i)z=26$

hence ,

$ a= (2-3i)\ \ $ and $\ b=2+3 i \implies ab=13$

Comment: how would I solve for tan^-1(3/2) ?

Comment: wait so for (a), the expression for b/a would simplify into e^i(tan^-1( 3 )

Comment: @ilikepi314: $tan ^{-1}\frac{3}{2} \approx 56.31^{\circ } $ ; you have to use scientific calculator to evaluate it because it not standard angle

Comment: $2 \times tan ^{-1}\frac{3}{2} \neq tan ^{-1}{3}$

Comment: how would I be able to simplify without a calculator?